# Python- Handling non ascii characters in file writing

Tags: python

When I run this code:

```
str1= "Ram's birthplace is “Ayodhya” in Uttar Pradesh"
file = open("abc.txt","w")
file.write(str1)
```

I got error:

> **SyntaxError**: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file, no encoding declared

Comment: `file = open("abc.txt","w",encoding="utf-8")`, or maybe it's decoding

Comment: are you using python 2.x ?

Comment: Same error still. I am using 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to set the encoding on the top of your script to prevent this error.

**Ex:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Do i need to import anything ?

Comment: No. Just set the above snippet to the first line of your script.

Answer (score 0):

As Rakesh pointed out, you can set an encoding cookie at the top of your script so that it handles non-ascii characters.

Alternatively, you could replace the double quotation marks around *Ayodhya* with ascii quotation marks:

`str1= "Ram's birthplace is \"Ayodhya\" in Uttar Pradesh"`